# Остановка программы Tcp

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность

new Thread(new ThreadStart(new Testing_one().Init)).Start();

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

// Token: 0x020009B0 RID: 2480
public class Testing_one
{
    // Token: 0x060052F9 RID: 21241
    private void Init()
    {
        try
        {
            ServerInit._listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888);
            ServerInit._listener.Start();
            Debug.Log("Ожидание подключений...");
            for (;;)
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = ServerInit._listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Debug.Log("Новое подключение");
                new Thread(new ThreadStart(new ClientObject(tcpClient).Process)).Start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.LogException(exception);
        }
        finally
        {
            TcpListener listener = ServerInit._listener;
            if (listener != null)
            {
                listener.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вынесите ожидание подключения в отдельный поток

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD вопросец так себе и ответ слишком очевидный.

Answer (score 1):

Вынесите ожидание подключения в отдельный поток

Comment: правильно я понял?Поправил вопрос

Comment: @Был вопрос, стал не вопрос... Я вообще на .NET не пишу

Answer (score 1):

```
        RCon.Setup();
        try {
     ServerInit._listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888);
            ServerInit._listener.Start();
            Debug.Log("Ожидание подключений...");  
          await Task.Run(() =>
            {

            for (;;) 
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = ServerInit._listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Debug.Log("Новое подключение");
                new Thread(new ThreadStart(new ClientObject(tcpClient).Process)).Start();
            }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Debug.LogException(exception);
        } finally {
            TcpListener listener = ServerInit._listener;
            if (listener != null)
            {
                listener.Stop();
            }
```

}

И метод пометь async

Comment: ClientObject async?

Comment: private async void Init()

Comment: видимо Task нету в 3.5 net framework https://pastebin.com/gdTMTwHh